# Replace a "new line" char with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to locate every string in a text file that contains the sequence "letter or number", "new line", "letter or number" then replace the "new line" with a "space".

This is what I've tried so far :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string pathFOSE = @"D:\Public\temp\FOSEtest.txt";     
     string output = Regex.Replace(pathFOSE, @"(?<=\w)\n(?=\w)", " ");                      

     string pathNewFOSE = @"D:\Public\temp\NewFOSE.txt";
     if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathNewFOSE))
     {
          // Create a file to write to. 
          using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(pathNewFOSE))
          {                
          }
     File.AppendAllText(pathNewFOSE, output);
     }
}
```

But all my program does is create a new text file, containing only this line `"D:\Public\temp\FOSEtest.txt"`

Any idea of what's happening ? Also is `\n` the correct way of searching for new lines in a text file in Windows7? Thanks

**Edit**: I made the change suggested by Avinash and added that I was working on Windows 7.

**Edit 2**: I think I need to understand why the `Replace` is taking place on the path string and not on the file it leads to before trying suggestions.

**Final Edit**: Everything is working thanks to stribizhev, I just copy pasted his answer. Thanks to everyone that responded !

Comment: The character(s) used for new line depend(s) on your operating system.

Comment: Not sure that's what you meant, but I replace `\n` by `Environment.NewLine` for the same result. I think I need to know why the path is being written in the text file first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, line breaks usually look like `\r\n` (caret return + line feed).
So, you can match linebreaks that are preceded and followed by an alphanumeric with

```
string output = Regex.Replace(pathFOSE, @"(?<=\w)\r\n(?=\w)", " ");
```

Mind that `\w` matches Unicode letters and an underscore, too. If you do not need that behavior (and only need to match English letters) use

```
string output = Regex.Replace(pathFOSE, @"(?i)(?<=[a-z0-9])\r\n(?=[a-z0-9])", " ");
```

If you have a mixture of line breaks from various OSes or programs, you may use

```
string output = Regex.Replace(pathFOSE, @"(?i)(?<=[a-z0-9])(?:\r\n|\n|\r)(?=[a-z0-9])", " ");
```

And in case there are multiple line breaks, add a `+` quantifier `(?:\r\n|\n|\r)+`.

To perform search and replace on the file contents, you need to read the file in.

You can do it with

```
var pathFOSE = @"D:\Public\temp\FOSEtest.txt";
var contents = File.ReadAllText(pathFOSE);
var output = Regex.Replace(contents, @"(?i)(?<=[a-z0-9])(?:\r\n|\n|\r)(?=[a-z0-9])", " ");

var pathNewFOSE = @"D:\Public\temp\NewFOSE.txt";
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathNewFOSE))
{
    File.WriteAllText(pathNewFOSE, output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, this will be very helpful once I understand why the `Replace` is taking place on the path string and not on the file it leads to

Comment: You need to read the file first: `var contents = File.ReadAllText(pathFOSE);`. And perform the replacements on the `contents` and then write the modified contents to the new file.

Comment: Ok, I think you just need `ReadAllText`. I am thinking a bit faster than typing :)

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same result

Comment: Oh yes, just realized what I have done... Please show me the right way ;)

Comment: I have correct my answer. Your code was rather messy I should say :)

Comment: What a great answer, thank you for helping a newbie and being so patient !

Answer (score 4):

You need to use positive lookbehind.

```
Regex.Replace(pathFOSE, @"(?<=\w)\n(?=\w)", " "); 
                            ^
```

`(?=\w)` called positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a word character.

or

```
Regex.Replace(pathFOSE, @"(?<=\w)[\r\n]+(?=\w)", " ");
```

Comment: I am still only getting a text file with the path written in it. I guess there is another problem, thank you for helping me with this one though

Comment: try `@"(?<=\w)\r\n(?=\w)"`, since windows use carriage return char also. or `@"(?<=\w)[\r\n]+(?=\w)"`